# converting a int char into int without changing the value in java

Tags: java, casting, char, int, ascii

I have a String, for example: `s2 =  "SPX8X55";`
I want that each letter of the alphabet of this String to have its own value:

> (A = 1, B = 2, ... Z = 26)

I have figured out that I can assign the chars to an int number via a foreach-loop. 
As I'm only using capital letters I use c - 64 because A is number 65 in ASCII, so 65 - 64 = 1 => A has the number 1.

```
for (char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
    int charzahl = c - 64;
    System.out.println(charzahl);
}
```

BUT I want the numbers to STAY numbers. If I use this foreach-loop, I get -8 for 8 and -11 for 5.
I have thought about an "if-statement" like:

```
if ( c >= 0 || c <= 0){ ... }
```

to check if there are any numbers for c. If I cast these chars into an int I get -8 and -11 back again.
How can I cast them into an int to stay as they are? My purpose is to add all numbers together at the end with a for-loop.

Comment: "BUT I want the numbers to STAY numbers" - what *exactly* do you mean by this? Do you mean "I want digits '0' to '9' to stay as values 48-57 inclusive?"

Comment: `if ( c >= 0 || c <= 0)` And which number would not be either greater or equal to zero or less than or equal to zero? Seems like a pointless if.

Comment: I want that 5 stays 5 but as an int and not as -11.

Comment: [Char.isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))

Comment: Do you want A and 1 to both become 1?

Comment: If there would be an A AND an 1 in the String, then - yes.

Comment: Do you mean `int charzahl = (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c - ('A' + 1) : c;`? Or, maybe, `int charzahl = (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c - ('A' + 1) : (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? c - '0' : 0;`?

Comment: I'll make it a bit more precise: My output numbers are: 19, 16, 24, -8, 24, -11, -11. But they should be: 19, 16, 24, 8, 24, 5, 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different calculations for different ranges. Since it's only a few, this syntax is clear.

```
int charzahl = 
    (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c - 'A' + 1 : 
    (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? c - '0' : 
    0;
```

Comment: BTW—Java uses the UTF-16 encoding of [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html), not the ASCII encoding of ASCII.